# using NSE in data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, nse

I have a data.table called `client`, that has the following columns:

```r
    "location"   "clientID"   "gender"     "age"  "startYear"  "ag1"        "ag2"
```

There is the `age` variable and two factorised versions of it: `ag1` and `ag2`.

Now i want to group my data, using the `ag1` factorization:

```r
agegroup <- sym(agegroup)
clientTotal <- client[,.(NOinsureds=length(clientID)), by = .(gender, agegroup, startYear)]
```

which results in an error:

> `Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output Error in`
>   [.data.table`(clientData, , .(NOinsureds = length(clientID)), :
>   column or expression 2 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type symbol. Do not quote
>   column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]`

I assume this is because the `NSE`. I have read a little about it online, which is why i included `agegroup <- sym(agegroup)`, but it does not seem to work.

Any suggestions?

I will be manipulating the data quite a lot, and i will also be writing functions, so maybe keep that in mind when recommending solutions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your problem seems related to NSE. Rather than using `.()`, you can use character vectors names in `by`.

```r
agegroup <- "ag1"
clientTotal <- client[,.(NOinsureds=length(clientID)),
                        by = c("gender", agegroup, "startYear")]
```

`data.table` syntax is very nice in function because `NSÈ  is not hard to apply. If it can help you, I wrote a post on the subject of [NSE in data.table](https://linogaliana.netlify.com/post/datatable/datatable-nse/). You can also find many resources online.

Comment: the point, is  that i do not want to use character vectors because my input will be changing (as part of a function). Is i want to have my data grouped by the ag2 i will just change `agegroup <- "ag2"`, then `agegroup <- sym(agegroup)` and use `agegroup` in `data.table`... does it make sense?

Comment: I don't understand why you need `sym`. Could you show an example of what you want to do ? In my example (just edited), you can use agegroup <- "ag1" or agegroup <- "ag2"

Comment: If you need to use your variable in `i` or `j` dimension of the `[...]`, an example would help

Comment: your post is great btw, very helpful

Comment: Thanks, happy it can help others !

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarifications in the comments, you should be able to use `get()`.

```
library(data.table)
agegroup <- 'ag1'
clientTotal <- client[,.(NOinsureds=length(clientID)), by = .(gender, age = get(agegroup), startYear)]
```

Consider this example:

```
library(data.table)
cars <- data.table(mtcars)
strBy <- "carb"
cars[,.(avg.mpg = mean(mpg)), by = .(gear,Carborator = get(strBy))]
    gear Carborator  avg.mpg
 1:    4          4 19.75000
 2:    4          1 29.10000
 3:    3          1 20.33333
 4:    3          2 17.15000
 5:    3          4 12.62000
 6:    4          2 24.75000
 7:    3          3 16.30000
 8:    5          2 28.20000
 9:    5          4 15.80000
10:    5          6 19.70000
11:    5          8 15.00000
```